# Replace strings in entire dataframe if they are present in a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, replace

Thank you for your time visiting my post. I have the following dataframe below:

```
df1
        col1                                    col2
    1   virginia is cold, canada is cold too    virginia is cold, canada is cold too
    2   florida, virginia, washington are good  florida, virginia, washington are good
    3   georgia, alabama, virginia are hot      virginia is cold, canada is cold too
    4   virginia, ohio, new castle are great    hawaii, nebreska is wonderful
    5   hawaii, nebreska is wonderful           virginia, ohio, new castle are great
```

Also, I have a list containing a string:

```
lst = ['virginia', 'hot', 'too']
```

I want to replace the string in the entire dataframe with "xxxxxx" if it matches one of the strings in the list. For instance, my dataframe would look like this after replacement:

```
 df1
            col1                                    col2
        1   xxxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxxx   xxxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxxx
        2   florida, xxxxxx, washington are good    florida, xxxxxx, washington are good
        3   georgia, alabama, xxxxxx are xxxxxx     xxxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxxx
        4   xxxxxx, ohio, new castle are great      hawaii, nebreska is wonderful
        5   hawaii, nebreska is wonderful           xxxxxx, ohio, new castle are great
```

So far, I have tried but it does not work:

```
df1 = df1.replace(lst, "xxxxxx")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from the list of words and use *regex*:

```
lst = ['virginia', 'hot', 'too']
df1.replace({w: "xxxxxx" for w in lst}, regex=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
df1.replace(lst, 'x' * 5, regex=True)

                                  col1                                 col2
1  xxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxx  xxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxx
2  florida, xxxxx, washington are good  florida, xxxxx, washington are good
3    georgia, alabama, xxxxx are xxxxx  xxxxx is cold, canada is cold xxxxx
4    xxxxx, ohio, new castle are great        hawaii, nebreska is wonderful
5        hawaii, nebreska is wonderful    xxxxx, ohio, new castle are great
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to iterate over list `lst` like here:

```
import pandas as pd

...
lst = ['virginia', 'hot', 'too']
for s in lst:
    df1.replace(s, 'xxxxx', inplace=True)

print( df1)
```